# Images in the first column of a listview in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm with a little problem on a project.

As you can see in the image, I have a `ListView` with some data pulled from a List of objects from the class person. This class also has an attribute that keep the path of an image chosen by the user, which is supposed to show on the first column of the `ListView`, where it says teste.

[image]

I've tried the following code:

```
ImageList imgs = new ImageList();
imgs.ImageSize = new Size(40, 40);
foreach (user list in Global.userslist)
{
    imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(list.Photo));
}
listview1.SmallImageList = imgs;
foreach (user list in Global.userslist)
{
    imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(list.Photo));
    listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "teste", Convert.ToString(list.Id), lista.Name, list.Birthday.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") }));
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `DataGridView` instead?

Comment: I've thought about that, But there is a lot of work already done with this ListView and I can't seem to find out how to do cumulative searches with the DataGridView.

Comment: Your problem in above code is you forgot to set `ImageIndex` of your item.

Comment: I know how to do that on the designer, by adding an item manually. Not sure how to do it dynamically tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set [`ImageIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imageindex(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ImageKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imagekey(v=vs.110).aspx) property for the item to show the image.

You can pass the index or key in [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) of [`ListViewItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx). Also you can assign the value using the `ImageIndex` or `ImageKey` property.

**Example**

In your code, you can set the image key when adding them to `ImageList`:

```
imgs.Images.Add(list.Id.ToString(), Image.FromFile(list.Photo));
```

Then when creating items, use the `ImageKey`:

```
listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { ... ... }, list.Id.ToString()));
```